# FontAwesome Label renderer iOS trouble

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, font-awesome

I am trying to figure out how to make this Android Example work with iOS:

```
using System;
using md.UserControls;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

namespace md.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class FontAwesomeLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                Control.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets,
                    "Fonts/" + FontAwesomeLabel.FontAwesomeName + ".ttf");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The part with issues is this:

```
Control.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets,
                    "Fonts/" + FontAwesomeLabel.FontAwesomeName + ".ttf");
```

Control.Typeface or just Typeface is giving some issues (red underline).

What is typeface in iOS?

Hope someone can help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just define a `Style` for the labels that you want to have this font type. You could do it in XAML, by defining the `FontFamily` like so:

```
<Style x:Key="NameOfYourLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily">
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android">Fonts/FontAwesome.otf#FontAwesome</On>
            <On Platform="UWP">/Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.otf#FontAwesome</On>
            <On Platform="iOS">FontAwesome</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Make sure that you add the *.otf (or *.ttf) font file into the `Resources` folder and make sure you add a specific key in your `info.plist` file, like so:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Fonts/FontAwesome.otf</string>
</array>
```

NOTE: In my case the Fonts file sits in the Resources/Fonts/ directory

[image]

EDIT: What's actually happening under the hood when setting `FontFamily`, is exactly the same thing that you're doing in your renderer. Check out `UpdateFont` method in `LabelRenderer` in [Xamarin.Forms github sources](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/a94074463efe263cfe3056f6e1c65e65c2fac86f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/LabelRenderer.cs#L170) and  [`ToTypeFace`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/9fe5372c1d80ca8fcff0c4fc397d25f91f6b61d3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/FontExtensions.cs#L48) method called on in there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [Iconize](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize/tree/master/src/Plugin.Iconize) instead of writing your own custom renderers.

It's a simple plugin that allows you to use a lot of icon fonts (like Font Awesome).

**App.xaml.cs (initialisation of the plugin):**

```
Iconize.With(new FontAwesomeModule());
```

After you initialised it you can use it like this:

**XAML Page:**

```
xmlns:iconize="clr-namespace:Plugin.Iconize;assembly=Plugin.Iconize"

<iconize:IconLabel Text="fa-info" />
```

**C# Page:**

```
new IconLabel
{
    Text = "fa-info",
    FontSize = 55
};
```

Comment: I have tried implementing this but have some issues. Added the first line as you described but getting error with: new FontAwesomeModule()

Any idea on that?

Comment: @Mansa You also need this package if you want to use FontAwesome: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome/2.0.0.37-beta

Comment: OK, got this error when trying to install: Could not add xam.plugin.iconize.FontAwesome? Maybe this is the error: Detected package downgrade: Xam.Plugin.Iconize from 2.0.0.37-beta to 1.0.10. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 md (>= 1.0.0) -> Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome (>= 2.0.0.37-beta) -> Xam.Plugin.Iconize (>= 2.0.0.37-beta) 
 md (>= 1.0.0) -> Xam.Plugin.Iconize (>= 1.0.10)

Comment: Both packages should have this version number: 2.0.0.37-beta. You may need to enable preview builds in your NuGet package manager.

Comment: OK, now both packages is installed, but I still get the red line below: new FontAwesomeModule()? What to do?

Comment: @Mansa What kind of error message are you getting on the red line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179471/discussion-between-mansa-and-trevi-awater).

Comment: Not sure how to use it though. Where do I put my icon: <iconize:IconLabel mvx:Bi.nd="Text Icon;" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" />?